# Can my iPhone automatically send me an email when I turn it on?

Tags: iphone, email, notes.app

I had my iphone repaired by someone advertising on eBay.  I opened the package containing my iPhone 4s and when I turned it on, an email appeared in my gmail account that I sent to myself, which I didn't, that contained information I had in my iPhone notes.  Is it possible that the person who repaired my phone did this?  Now, I cannot find the note that was sent in my "notes."

Answer (score 1):

No, the phone can't email itself. He probably went into your accounts, checked your email address, and made a backup of your notes by emailing the stuff to your email address. That's what people do sometimes to remind themselves about stuff the next day or later when you read your emails.

If he sent it to your email address, and then read his own email, it is flagged as read/seen, and won't appear as a new/unseen email on any other email client. So this means you could have missed the notification, but he sure did email it to your email address from your email from your phone.

Hope this explains it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I didn't know that could be done.  What is odd, is that it was only one note from a long time ago that was emailed to my gmail account and I now can't find that note in my notes file.  Is there a way to send the note to gmail and automatically delete it from your iPhone notes after it is emailed?

Comment: Nope, only you can delete Notes manually, as a developer myself, there is no API for us to delete notes from the Notes app. Might have sent it through email, reset your settings and then setup your email again. Notes can be backed up through iCloud, go to www.icloud.com and log in, then see if your notes are there.

Comment: I may have figured it out.  My repaired phone that I sent to be repaired had an old SIMM card in it with different settings.  Could that have been why it sent me an email when I turned it on?